# Sharepoint 2010 alerts for expired dates for list items NO CODE

Tags: sharepoint, custom-lists

I have a simple list of account holders, emails, and dates their certificates expire.
That is all in the list nothing more.

I wish to alert them by automatic email (that I will compose) to remind them to contact me because their certificates will soon expire.

I have seen nothing OOB that addresses this.  I wish to avoid using javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the list is in Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Sharepoint workflow "x" days before expiry date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249366/start-sharepoint-workflow-x-days-before-expiry-date)