# Customize Sharepoint Alerts

Tags: sharepoint, templates, customization, alerts

Is it possible to customize the e-mail templates of Sharepoint server, in which, i don't have access for files and Central Administration. I'm using Sharepoint Designer to connect and edit my site currently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without having access to the files? Unfortunately no. The alert templates are read from an xml document in the 12-hive.

The alternative would be to mimic the alert functionality through a custom workflow in SPD that sends an email to a designated group. But this takes the customization out of the hands of the user which may not be desired.

Comment: This really is the only other way to customize the emails

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to create any custom code, because it leads my site to the category they call "custom solution". And they want very high fees to deploy any custom code.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the emails sent by workflows then yes

http://unitedsupplyco.sharepointsite.net/publicfacing/bensblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=49

If you mean the email alerts send OOTB with SharePoint then you need more access that you have.

[Customizing Alert Notifications and Alert Templates in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)

[How To: Customizing alert emails using IAlertNotifyHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx)

There are various 3rd party and open source apps that will let you do this without modifying xml files or programming but they still need to be installed (disclaimer, one of these is my own product)

[Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)