# Sharepoint 2010 RTM alerts templates

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to modify and set alert templates on a SP (working on a copy of alerttemplates.xml), but I'd like to deploy them just on some specific sites, not the whole farm. Is this possible? I'm using SharePoint 2010 RTM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes take effect at the site collection level (aka top level site) and include all subsites in them

[stsadm -o updatealerttempaltes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278299(office.12).aspx)

If you want more granular control you would have to look into IAlertNotifier, workflow or various 3rd party apps.

[SO - Customise SharePoint Alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328773/customize-sharepoint-alerts)