# Condition Based Notification - Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a list with lists of all the certificates being used in my project.

I want to setup a notification (email) if certification expires (or say a week before expiration).

I would like to know solutions with and without code deployment (feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different options (workflow/custom dev/3rd party and open source products) coverd in this post

- [SO - Dated reminders in SharePoint
  calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a SharePoint Designer Workflow (meets your requirements), [check this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102376561033.aspx), scroll down until you find the part it deals with the "Pause Until Date" activity.

Comment: This solution looks fine but "Pause Until Date" part looks messy, I would rather have list trigger a notification. Would there be a better solution using development or any other easier approach? Updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: I dont have a SPDesigner right now but I think the date you pause until can be dynamic. With Development you need to look at SPJobDefinitions, info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look through the Information Management Policy Settings in your List Settings and see if you can use the content expiration to achieve this. You can trigger a workflow to run (e.g. one that sends a notification email) on an item based on a date field in your list.

So, for example, you can have it fire off an email on Created Date + 10 days to notify whomever of its pending expiration

Comment: Could you provide some reference for triggering a workflow based on item. It seems like pretty common and trivial task, but I am unable to get it working so far.