# Read ListItems from Sharepoint List Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have a custom list in sharepoint, which contains two colums such as date and person. Based on some condition on date, i need to send a mail to the respective person. This is my requirements. So i need to know how to get the ListItem programmatically. If anyother alternate way such as, through web services, help me put step by step pls....

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void DeleteAllItemsUsingBatch()  
   {  
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySharePointServer"))  
    {  
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/");  
        SPList list = web.Lists["Links"];  
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)  
        {  
            // item is list item 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly complete coverage of the topic :-

[SO - Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)