# Alert on a scheduled end date for a document in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, scheduling, alerts

When I set a scheduled end date on a document in SharePoint 2010, I want to to alert users when the item reaches this date. Is this possible in SharePoint 2010 without custom code?

Answer (score 1):

By customizing alert templates. Creating custom filters by using Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML) queries in the element in the alert templates.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer from a related question:

[Set a review date on a sharepoint 2010 document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981635/set-a-review-date-on-a-sharepoint-2010-document/3984377#3984377)

Answer (score 0):

This answer details a few different ways to do this - workflow, scheduled jobs, open source and commercial add-ons.

[Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)