# Set a review date on a sharepoint 2010 document

Tags: date, sharepoint-2010, document, alert, review

In sharepoint 2010 I need to be able to set a review date on a document and be emailed when this review date is reached. Is this possible?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1):

I would create a very simple Workflow for this. You could just fire up Sharepoint Designer, create a small Workflow which checks whether the document in question has been reviewed and otherwise send an e-mail or a task to some person.
Try out Sharepoint Designer & Workflows if you haven't done so. Reminders are a very easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This answer details a few different ways to do this - workflow, scheduled jobs, open source and commercial add-ons.

[Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)

Answer (score 0):

To make it the most robust solution, I would suggest to customize the Alerts framework of SharePoint. SharePoint allows following customizations (as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802949.aspx)

- Adding or removing buttons from the
  alert e-mails.
- Changing the cascading style sheet
  used to format e-mail alerts. This is
  particularly useful for sites that
  want to create a consistent
  appearance.
- Changing the latency of "immediate"
  alerts by adjusting the default timer
  interval.
- Override the templates used to create
  e-mail or SMS alerts, either by
  creating a new template or by setting
  the SPList.AlertTemplate property.
- **Creating custom filters by using Collaborative Application Markup
  Language (CAML) queries in the
   element in the alert
  templates.**
- Programmatically setting or changing
  the mobile messaging service provider
  (MSP) that forwards SMS alerts to
  mobile telephones.
- Adding custom event handlers that
  respond when a user creates or
  modifies an alert. Also, custom
  handlers that respond to the alert
  sending event can be created.
- Programming the alerts framework by
  using the SharePoint Foundation
  object model. For more information
  about how to customize alerts
  programmatically, see SPAlert.

If your list supports sending alerts based on a View, you are lucky, A NO CODE SOLUTION is already there for you. You can create a View with filter condition like "DueDate is equal to [Today]" (and possibly "AssignedTo is equal to [Me]) and then subscribe to any changes to that view.

If you end up with custom alert filter, following links may get you started:
http://egrimmett.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/custom-alerts-part-2-filters/

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108025726/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you can set an Alert on a view if the view contains filters - so your "No Code" solution won't work (at least on a test 2007 and 2010 system I've got in front of me).

Comment: It may not be due to filter but some restrictions with Document Libraries I think. Because I was able to setup alerts in filtered views of the Tasks list.

Comment: It doesn't work and the reason is that you will only get an alert if someone changes the item WHILE it's in the "Due Today" view. e.g. set up a task for tomorrow and wait for 1 day. You will not get the alert.