# Trigger site workflow once a day in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, triggers, workflow, designer

I'm have created a site workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010 which sends an email if the status field, of any item, is 'closed'. I would like to trigger this workflow every day a 10am.

How can I do this in Sharepoint Designer 2010? Or is it only possible trough code?

Thanks

Comment: "Every day at 10am" would only be possible with workflows with workarounds. You will need to develop a timer job which is only possible in code.

Comment: @moontear is right.. see also http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26253/complete-task-by-4pm-or-else or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars