# Sharepoint 2010 workflow to send automatic email notification before document expiry

Tags: sharepoint, document

In Sharepoint 2010, As part of an approval workflow process, I would like to implement a Automatic Email notification before the  document expiry.

Lets say whenever the document is "Approved",my custom approval workflow calculates "Approved Date" as well as "Expiry Date".

What will be the best approach to send automatic email notification before 1 week of the expiry date.

I do not want to do the "Pause until date" logic using SPD 2010.

Comment: FYI, there's a SharePoint Stack Exchange: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the Pause Until logic in a workflow then I can't see how you will be able to do this using workflow.

This post has some alternative options such as Timer Jobs that may help you -

[Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)